# Convert cuDF data frame column to 1 or 0 for “true”/“false” values

Tags: rapids, cudf

I am using RAPIDS (0.9 release) docker container. How can I do the following with RAPIDS cuDF?

`df['new_column'] = df['column_name'] > condition
df[['new_column']] *= 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the same way as with pandas.

```py
import cudf

df = cudf.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,4]})
df['new'] = df['a'] >= 3
df['new'] = df['new'].astype('int') # could use int8, int32, or int64

# could also do (df['a'] >= 3).astype('int')
df

    a   new
0   0   0
1   1   0
2   2   0
3   3   1
4   4   1
```